# Having divs "float" around

Tags: jquery, web

Sorry for the vague title, I can't really figure out another way to name it.

If you take a look at [my page](http://chigstuff.com/new/public_html/index.html), and click the button that says "hi", it'll make the top box disappear, and the bottom box take its place. Now, when the bottom box moves up top, it does it in an instant. How can I get it so that once the top box disappears, the bottom box "floats" up there, gracefully. Any good way with jQuery that I could accomplish it?

You can see a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UBEmx/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure, there are two main ways:

**Easy**: use the [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) animation on the upper box and what's beneath it should slide up to take its place.

```
$('#box-1').slideUp();
```

**hard**: use the jQuery [animations](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate a property on the lower box after the hide animation completes on the first

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead of a fadeToggle.  This way your jQuery stays almost exactly the same and you keep your on/off click functionality.  You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UBEmx/1/

If you change your `min-height` in the `box` class to just `height`, you get a MUCH better animation.

css:

```
.box 
{
   background-image: url("/new/public_html/img/BlackFadedBG.png");
   border: 2px solid black;
   max-height: 400px;
   max-width: 600px;
   height: 200px; /*here*/
   min-width: 300px; 
}
```

javascript:

```
$("#click").click(function() {   
  $("#box-1").slideToggle();  
});
```